# Vuejs @click event works wrong from time to time

Tags: vue.js, onclick, toggle

Recenty, I noticed that the checkboxes that I wrote a click event worked incorrectly from time to time. Not everytime but sometimes their @click event works in reverse. Here is what I am trying to tell;

```
  <label class="form-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" @click="showElement = !showElement"/>
  </label>
```

I have a simple form switch and there are some css on it which I didn't put here, it looks like a toggle switch. It toggles a data which is `showElement`. The default state of the data is false and when you click on the toggle it becomes true and false respectively.

```
<div v-show="showElement>
    some content here 
</div>
```

When the showElement is true I want to display the above div, and when it becomes false, I want it to be hidden. There is no problem with that. But here is my question;

If my observation is corret, usually when the project is started for the first time, in other words, when I type `npm run serve` and start the project, I immadiately go and check if it is working fine or not so I click on the checkbox very quickly over and over andsometimes the click event breaks down and starts working backwards. I mean, when the switch is off, the content is visible, when it is false, the div is showing, but it should be reversed. This happens sometimes when I browse the other pages of the project and return to this component. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? In the first version of the code it was like below;

```
  <label class="form-switch" @click="showElement = !showElement>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
  </label>
```

I accidentally typed the click event to the label element instead of input. I thought that might be the problem. I am still thinking that is the problem but the bug that I explained above still happens sometimes. Do you know why? Can anyone explain?

Comment: If you put that click event into the input, is it improving the behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually i find that with checkboxes in VueJS @Click is not the way to go. Try to use @Change event instead. This should make it more consistent.

The reason behind this is that the click event triggers before the value has been updated. Therefore creating the risk of it overwriting the old value instead of the newly updated one

EDIT:

I actually think in this case you might even be able to get around this by simply adding a v-model to the checkbox like so:

v-model="showElement" instead of having either @click or @change.

Verison 1:

```
   <label class="form-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" @change="showElement = !showElement"/>
  </label>
```

Version 2:

```
 <label class="form-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="showElement"/>
  </label>
```

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4wykp2u/4/
Hope this makes sense

Comment: As I mentioned above, I accidentally typed the click="showElement = !showElement" part in the label element, not in the input. So that caused the problem. Now It works okay, but I will revised them as change. That helped a lot. I didnt know that thing about click triggering before value update.